# Using pivot table to generate "training matrix"

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table of "CertificateEntries" which goes along the lines of;

```
Entity_ID | Certificate_ID | CertificateExpiry
1         | 1              | dd/mm/YYYY
1         | 2              | dd/mm/YYYY
```

etc., etc. It's a many-to-many relationship essentially, entities can have many certs and certs can be assigned to many entities.

What I would like to do is have this pivoted so that the list of certificates is the columns;

```
Entity_ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
1         | T | T | F | F |
2         | T | F | F | T |
```

I can't quite grasp how to get this done, all the online examples seem to indicate that you need COUNT, MAX, AVG, etc. Ideally I would love to have the expiry in place of the T/F but if that's not possible, I can understand...

If someone could help point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
begin try
create table #test 
(Entity_ID int,Certificate_ID int,CertificateExpiry date)

insert into #test values(1,1,'01/01/2013')
insert into #test values(1,2,'05/01/2013')
insert into #test values(1,5,'01/05/2013')
insert into #test values(1,9,'05/12/2013')

insert into #test values(2,1,'10/05/2013')
insert into #test values(2,2,'12/03/2013')
insert into #test values(4,6,'2/05/2013')
insert into #test values(5,8,'4/09/2013')

--select * from #test

DECLARE @Certificate_Ids VARCHAR(8000)


SELECT @Certificate_Ids = COALESCE(@Certificate_Ids + '], [', '') + cast(Certificate_ID as varchar(20)) FROM 
(select distinct Certificate_ID from #test ) as a


Set @Certificate_Ids='['+@Certificate_Ids+']'

--print @Certificate_Ids


Declare @query varchar(max)


Set @query=
'SELECT
Entity_ID, ' + @Certificate_Ids + ' 
FROM #test
PIVOT
(
  MAX(CertificateExpiry)
  FOR Certificate_ID in (' + @Certificate_Ids + ' )   
) A'

print @query

exec(@query)


drop table #test
end try

begin catch
drop table #test
end catch
```

Comment: So close, thankyou. I really need the @Certificate_Ids as part of the query if at all possible?

Comment: I do not understand. Is '1','2','3','4' not the certificate_id in the output?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer a single SQL statement. At the moment you have one to populate Certificate_Ids and then one to generate the pivot table. Is it possible to combine them?

Comment: As it's in some C# code, I pre-generate the list of cert ids, add in the [] and insert it into the command using string.Format()
Thanks!

Comment: @FizzBuzz So you can see the value of '@Certificate_Ids'. Format the string accordingly and pass that as a parameter. Then no need of find '@Certificate_Ids' in SQL procedure.